# UIWebview set is expandable and collapsing cells in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to set a uiwebview in tableview webview data will be differen size so as per the content of webview expanding the cell must be adjust how to do that

Comment: `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` would give you the webview's height. Listen to webviews delegates, once its done loading just reload that particular row in table and adjust height accordingly. If webview is already loaded, then pass the scrollview content size height for that cell.

Comment: i am using the HVTableView class as a third party i cannon do that because all objects in tableview content view are given as tag values but i dont know how to give do you have any examples which are in tableview expanding and collapsing when collapsing it shows webview